# how to print a phrase that starts with P: in a list of tuple

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to get the function of a protein. the function is located with a list of tuples:

```
my_seq=[('EMBL', 'AF079160', 'AAC28386.2', '-', 'Genomic_DNA'), ('EMBL', 'AJ564626', 'CAD92097.1', '-', 'Genomic_DNA'), ('EMBL', 'AP008226', 'BAD70067.1', '-', 'Genomic_DNA'), ('RefSeq', 'WP_011227803.1', 'NC_006461.1'), ('RefSeq', 'YP_143510.1', 'NC_006461.1'), ('PDB', '2CWA', 'X-ray', '1.96 A', 'A=1-263'), ('PDBsum', '2CWA', '-'), ('SMR', 'Q5SLP9', '-'), ('STRING', '300852.55771626', '-'), ('EnsemblBacteria', 'BAD70067', 'BAD70067', 'BAD70067'), ('GeneID', '3167973', '-'), ('KEGG', 'ttj:TTHA0244', '-'), ('PATRIC', 'fig|300852.9.peg.244', '-'), ('eggNOG', 'ENOG4105Z8H', 'Bacteria'), ('eggNOG', 'COG0629', 'LUCA'), ('HOGENOM', 'HOG000023350', '-'), ('KO', 'K03111', '-'), ('OMA', 'ARGMNHV', '-'), ('BioCyc', 'TTHE300852:G1GKC-252-MONOMER', '-'), ('EvolutionaryTrace', 'Q5SLP9', '-'), ('Proteomes', 'UP000000532', 'Chromosome'), ('GO', 'GO:0003697', 'F:single-stranded DNA binding', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule'), ('GO', 'GO:0006310', 'P:DNA recombination', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule'), ('GO', 'GO:0006281', 'P:DNA repair', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule'), ('GO', 'GO:0006260', 'P:DNA replication', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule'), ('CDD', 'cd04496', 'SSB_OBF', '2'), ('HAMAP', 'MF_00984', 'SSB', '1'), ('InterPro', 'IPR012340', 'NA-bd_OB-fold'), ('InterPro', 'IPR000424', 'Primosome_PriB/ssb'), ('InterPro', 'IPR011344', 'ssDNA-bd'), ('PANTHER', 'PTHR10302', 'PTHR10302', '2'), ('Pfam', 'PF00436', 'SSB', '2'), ('SUPFAM', 'SSF50249', 'SSF50249', '2'), ('TIGRFAMs', 'TIGR00621', 'ssb', '2'), ('PROSITE', 'PS50935', 'SSB', '2')]
```

They are located in an ontology section GO: `('GO', 'GO:0006310', 'P:DNA recombination', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule')`, `('GO', 'GO:0006281', 'P:DNA repair', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule')`, `('GO', 'GO:0006260', 'P:DNA replication', 'IEA:UniProtKB-UniRule')`,

They are always preceded by P: i.e 'P:DNA repair'

I needed the output to be in a multiline format:
DNA recombination
DNA repair
DNA replication

```
my_list=(list(reduce(operator.concat, my_seq)))# convert to a list
b=','.join(my_list)# to convert to a string. 
import re
re.findall(r'^P:*\w+',(b), re.M) #tried re 

 [] #I am getting
```

I needed the output to be in a multiline format:
DNA recombination
DNA repair
DNA replication

Comment: insert the import for reduce function.

Comment: Can you show us the expected output? We don't know what "DNA recombination DNA repair DNA replication" means. Do you care about the original tuple groups?

Comment: When you are using the `re.M` (MULTILINE) flag, the `^` character matches both at the start of the entire input string, and also after newlines. However, there's no newlines in your input. Maybe you want to use `'\n'.join(my_list)`?

Answer (score -1):

See if this is what you wanted.

```
from functools import reduce
import operator
my_list=(list(reduce(operator.concat, my_seq)))# convert to a list
b=','.join(my_list)# to convert to a string.
import re
re.findall(r'P\:[\w ]+',(b), re.M)
```

Comment: I'll add explanation if needed.

Answer (score -1):

I did that lazy coder, but forgot to put in my solution online. The hiccup appeared in `re.findall` syntax. Your solution worked.

this is my final code, let me know if you make it streamlined:

```py
from Bio import ExPASy
from Bio import SwissProt
import operator
from functools import reduce
import re
handle = ExPASy.get_sprot_raw('Q5SLP9')
record = SwissProt.read(handle)
my_seq=record.cross_references
my_list=(list(reduce(operator.concat, my_seq)))
joinedlist=','.join(my_list)
my_GO=re.findall(r'P\:[\w ]+',joinedlist, re.M)
pattern = re.compile(r"P:")
result = [pattern.sub("", match) for match in my_GO]
print result[0]
print result[1]
print result[2]
```